# Why does automatic commenting selection in Xcode use // for .sh scripts?

Tags: xcode, bash, comments

I am using Xcode version 5.1.1 on Mac OS X to write Bash shell scripts. When I use Xcode to write a Perl script (.pl), the automatic commenting of a selection (`editor`->`structure`->`comment selection`) uses hash symbols (`#`) whereas with the Bash script (.sh) the auto commenting uses double forward slashes (`//`). When I run the Bash script the commenting doesn't appear to work unless I replace the `//` with `#`.

I tried running a single line in the Mac terminal to test this out:

```
// echo "hello world"
```

and get the error

```
-bash: //: is a directory
```

but

```
# echo "hello world"
```

works fine with the commenting.

I am wondering:

1. Why is the commenting using Xcode changed to `//` for the .sh script, as compared to `#` for the .pl script, and is there a way to change these settings in Xcode?
2. Is `//` a proper method of commenting for bash scripts, and if so, why doesn't it work in the Mac terminal?

Comment: `//` is not a shell comment. I don't know why xcode would get that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to question 2, no, `//` is not valid syntax in bash. `#` is the correct symbol to use. As for *why* the commenting syntax is changed, I'm not sure. I could only speculate that if Xcode doesn't recognise the extension, it defaults to the settings for a language which uses `//`, of which there are many (including Objective-C, a language commonly developed in using Xcode).

Comment: Thank you very much! As a follow up to question 1) Do you know of a way to re-set the default settings for a specific Xcode filetype (i.e. make the default .sh file settings for commenting and indentation the same as for .pl)?

Comment: Absolutely no idea I'm afraid, I don't use XCode. I'm sure that information on how to change the default settings will be available elsewhere though.